# Using Python with BeautifulSoup to extract numbers (multiple spans and classes)

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use Python with BeautifulSoup in order to pull multiple numbers from a web page. I know I am doing something wrong though because my script is returning an empty array. The fact that there are multiple spans and classes confuses me as well. Here is a sample of the HTML data I am working with:

```
<td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1">
         <span>
          Autoworks
         </span>
        </td>
        <td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1">
         900009
        </td>
        <td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1">
         <p>
          uyi: 3456778, 33344778, 11199087
         </p>
         <p>
          PRY: 54675389
         </p>
        </td>
<td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1">
         AutoNone
        </td>
        <td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1">
         9998887
        </td>
        <td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1">
         <p>
          YUN: 232323, 6788889, 78695554
         </p>
         <p>
          IOY: 3444666, 2343233, 1232322
         </p>
        </td>
```

Here is my Python code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()

s.post('https://wiki.example.com/login', data={'user': "user1", 'password': 
'pass1'})

r = s.get('https://wiki.example.com/example/section')

data_payload = r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(data_payload, 'html.parser')
data = soup.findAll("span", {"class":"confluenceTd"})

print data
```

Again, I am only trying to pull the actual numbers. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In the HTML code, you do not have any spans that belong to the class "confluenceTd". That's why you get an empty list. For the sake of future discussion, I suggest that you shrink your code to the last three lines, because everything else is not related to the question. We expect you to produce the _minimal_ verifiable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you like to get all numbers present under specific class use regex/regular expressions to pull numbers and make sure requests is pulling html

```
 import requests,re
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 s = requests.Session()
 s.post('https://wiki.example.com/login', data={'user':"user1",'password': 'pass1'})
 r = s.get('https://wiki.example.com/example/section')
 data_payload = r.content
 soup = BeautifulSoup(data_payload, 'html.parser')
 data = soup.findAll("td", {"class":"confluenceTd"})
 for d in data:
    m=re.search('([0-9]+)',str(d.findAll(text=True)))
    if m:
       print m.group(0)
```